# Объект принадлежит NoneType, хотя по идее должен принадлежать классу bs4

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from requests import get

responce = get(site+user).text
soup = BS(responce, "lxml")
sec = soup.find(class_="l-page").find("div")
head = sec.find_all("div")[0]
```

`soup.find(class_="l-page")` почему-то является объектом класса NoneType, хотя должен, как я понимаю, быть объектом класса BeautifulSoup. А так кидает TypeError, т.к. нет атрибута find.

Comment: sec = soup.find(class_="l-page").find("div") у вас здесь ошибка, а точнее (class_="l-page") нет одного параметра. тега нет,  так я не вижу исходников HTML могу только предположить что вы хотели написать soup.find(("div". class_="l-page")

Comment: >вы хотели написать soup.find(("div". class_="l-page")
Да, примерно так и хотел. Только не div, а section, но это не помогло, ошибка осталась прежней.

Comment: Значить не находмть искомые теги с классами